# Convert stored utc dates to datetimeoffset datatype

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, utc, datetimeoffset

We have thousands of historical UTC datetimes stored in a SQL Server database and we now want to change those columns to use the `datetimeoffset` datatype (currently `datetime`)

So I have altered the columns and changed the datatype. Now they all have a '+00:00' offset.

Since we are in NZ, I'm guessing next we would just update the data using `SWITCHOFFSET` with a '+12:00' offset?

However, that won't take into consideration DST, which makes the offset '+13:00' during DST periods?

Is there anyway to do this in SQL without a mapping table to DST switchover dates for the historical period?

Thanks

Comment: Decided to keep them as a utc `datetime` with an offset of '+00:00'

Answer (score 0):

Keeping them as `+00:00` is perfectly fine.  However, if you want to project them to a particular time zone (including DST calculation), you can use the `SwitchZone` method from my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) project.

```
UPDATE yourtable SET dto = Tzdb.SwitchZone(dto, 'Pacific/Auckland')
```